# How do I access an element in an Arraylist inside another Arraylist?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

So I'm working on an object-oriented java project that deals with Load Management at a shipping company. A journey has an origin, location, content and destination. A journey has one or more containers where it is possible to monitor the temperature, humidity and pressure in the container. So I want to get all the journey's on which a given container has been on (the container's history). All containers used for any given journey are stored in that journey's "**containerList**" (arraylist).

So the idea is the method "**containerHistory**" should look through the arraylist "**history**"(which contains completed journeys) and for each journey in the "**history**" arraylist, should look through the array list "**containerList**"  for each given journey and for each container in the array list "**containerList**" compare the given container's id to the one we are looking for( which in the below code will be represented by the string "**search**"

```
    public ArrayList<Journey> containerHistory(String search, ArrayList<Journey> history){
        ArrayList<Journey> containerhistorylist = new ArrayList<Journey>();
        for(Journey j : history) {
            for(Container c : j.getContainerList()) {
                if (c.getContainerId().contentEquals(search)) {
                    containerhistorylist.add(j);
                }
            }
        }
        return containerhistorylist;        
    }
```

Any idea on how to improve this code or an alternative way of going about this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with using Java 8 streams then the following code is possible:

```java
List<Journey> containerhistorylist = history
    .stream()
    .filter(j -> j.getContainerList()
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(c -> c.getContainerId().contentEquals(search)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```